# PHP Fix For Google Chrome Confirm Form Resubmission pop-up

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

I am trying to submit form data using POST method. But after submission when I refresh the page the 'Confirm Form Resubmission' popup appears. Now I have look at some other answers from this site, which suggest either using GET (I don't want to use GET, POST only) or use the header with Location: url for redirection. I tried that and it still doesn't fix the problem.

This could be a stupid mistake on my end so I apologize in advance. Please point of the problem from my code below.

Thanks in advance.

```
</head>



<body>

    <form action="PHPConfirmationResubmissionForm.php" method="POST">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

 <?

    if(isset($_POST["fname"]))
    {
        header('Location: http://localhost/web/PHP/PHPConfirmationResubmissionForm.php');

        $x = $_POST["fname"];
        echo "<br /> Firstname is $x";

    }



?>
</body>
```

Comment: Be careful with this!  Some browsers will post to the next URL.  It isn't standardized.  If you aren't careful, you could end up in an endless loop.  In addition, you've opened yourself up to a nasty XSS vulnerability.  Use `htmlspecialchars()` around any variable data used in an HTML context.

Comment: why do you care about refreshing the page?